# Solubility of raspberry ketone in paraffin oil

Tags: solubility

I want to dissolve raspberry ketones (RK) in paraffin oil, but I'm not sure about its solubility in it. I want to use this mixture for the fruit fly's behavioral study. Is it possible to dissolve the RK pheromone in paraffin oil?

Comment: Based on nothing more than looking at the structure I think it would have some solubility. This paper reports the solubility in some organic solvents  https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S016773221733218X

Comment: Do you mean [raspberry ketone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_ketone) as a substance (3-(p-hydroxyphenyl)propanal), mix of similar substances or [food dietary supplement formula](https://fitnessmuscle.eu/en/haya-labs-raspberry-ketones-500mg)? // For the substance itself, my opinion is it seems to be partially soluble, but better if little more polar solvent is used, what may not be applicable. OTOH, the concentration would not be probably high.

Comment: It is not soluble in paraffin oil, but soluble in glycerol, which is suitable for biological tests.

Comment: @Poutnik: Of course, raspberry ketone is a ketone. 4-(4-hydroxyphenyl)butan-2-one. But you knew that. ;)

Comment: @user55119 Hehe, you are right, I did not pay enough attention to the structure, for some strange reasons considering the ending methyl as hydrogen, not realizing it would not be a ketone. :-D